# What is this script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've never seen it used like this before:

```
<script src="{{ file.name_js }}"></script>
```

Is this better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something from a templating engine, such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or similar.

Everything between the brackets `{{` `}}` is handled server-side, likely so that the script files can be minified server-side easily and the file name be updated to the minified version, or something from a variable.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok.  Yeah, I am working on a project with masonry and it had that in there for the calls for jquery and the masonry js files/framework.

Answer (score 1):

looks like somekind of a [templating language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29) Django has the same kind of tags for example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like some form of template parsing, in which anything inside `{{ }}` parenthesis would get replaced to a specific value on the server side.